# Jackson: Serialise ArrayList not working?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am referring to this example [here](http://www.novixys.com/blog/jackson-json-serialization/) to serialize my object.

I have this initially and it works.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private String mediaitem_id;
    private String customer_id;
    private int quantity;

    public MyClass(String item, String customer, int quantity){
        this.mediaitem_id = item;
        this.customer_id = customer;
        this.quantity = quantity;    
    }

    public String toJson(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try{
            mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE);
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            log.error("Error converting MyClass to json " + this, ex);
        }

        return "";
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass("1234", "23234", 5);
```

myClass.toJson() gives the below, which is what I want:

```
{ mediaitem_id: '1234', customer_id: '23234', quantity: 5 }
```

But now I need to add an arraylist to the class and need to serialise it as well, so I add a new class Account:

```
public static class Account implements Serializable {
    public String accountname;
    public String accountid;

    public Account(String accountname, String accountid) {
        this.accountname = accountname;
        this.accountid = accountid;
    }
}

public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private String mediaitem_id;
    private String customer_id;
    private int quantity;
    private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyClass(String item, String customer, int quantity){
        this.mediaitem_id = item;
        this.customer_id = customer;
        this.quantity = quantity;    
    }

    public void addAccount(String accountname, String accountid) {
        Account anAccount = new Account(accountname, accountid);
        accounts.add(anAccount);
    }       

    public String toJson(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try{
            mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE);
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            log.error("Error converting MyClass to json " + this, ex);
        }

        return "";
    }
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass("1234", "23234", 5);
myClass.addAccount("acc-01", "a001");
myClass.addAccount("acc-02", "a002");
```

myClass.toJson() still gives the same:

```
{ mediaitem_id: '1234', customer_id: '23234', quantity: 5 }
```

What am I missing now?

I wanted to get something like:

```
{ mediaitem_id: '1234', customer_id: '23234', quantity: 5, accounts: [{accountname: 'acc-01', accountid: 'a001'}, {accountname: 'acc-02', accountid: 'a002'}]}
```

Comment: Feels like you're leaving out some details. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommed add your getter and setter for all property in your `MyClass` .

```
public String getMediaitem_id() {
        return mediaitem_id;
    }

    public void setMediaitem_id(String mediaitem_id) {
        this.mediaitem_id = mediaitem_id;
    }

    public String getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(String customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }
```

Comment: you are right @mrtasin, I put in the getter and the setter for List<Account> account and it's now working!